# Extracting cell data at a specific point in time in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

As the title says, I'm trying to extract the number from a cell at a specific date and time in Excel. In my example, I will be pulling information weekly from 3 particular cells. Ex. I want to pull the information on Friday's at 1:00PM. So I will want data on 7/1/16 1:00PM, 7/8/16 1:00PM, etc. During that exact time I want to pull a number from those cells and place it into a cell so I can create an automated trending graph.

It'll only be 3 numbers that I am pulling so doing this manually wouldn't be difficult, but who wants to do things manually? Especially in Excel. I can't find a specific formula that would complete this for me.

If anyone could provide any help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You would need VBA for this.  Is the file always open - ie. can it be guaranteed to be open at the required time?

Comment: Hmm, it wouldn't that's the thing. It might be a better idea to just input this manually. I figured VBA would be required, if there was something in Excel that would conduct this, I would be all for it. Thanks.